# Which application generates *.MAG, *.MOB and *.CAR files?

Tags: gps, file-formats, file-association

I have following type of files (I have tried FME too.I think they are DGPS generated file?)

1. ".MAG" , ".MOB" and ".CAR" extension files many more
2. ".SES" ,"ERR", "LOG" several

I have attached files in the [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1NvUoakjNxwcFpRcXdnSEtqNm8&usp=sharing)

```
Or see the Snapshots
```

[image: Snap1] [image: Snap2] [image: Snap3]

Now i want to know:

2. Which application generates these files?
3. How to read these files (esp ".MAG", ".MOB" and ".CAR") and
4. How to generate spatial data from these files (esp ".MAG", ".MOB" and ".CAR")

Comment: Some general observations/guesses on half of the files: 1) Looks like output from a Magellan GPS unit 2) .LOG looks like log file for general logging and tells you what was output 3) .SES looks to be more specific session logging about the processing 4) .ERR looks to be the error log. Also, look at the .LOG file, it tells you a _little bit_ about some of the other filetypes.

Comment: what about .CAR and .MOB?  How to read these magellan (.MAG) files?

Comment: This looks like multiple questions which do not fit the Q&A format of GIS SE very well.  I recommend that you focus on asking "Which application generates *.MAG, *.MOB and *.CAR files?" in this Question.

Comment: @PolyGeo  Thanks , Infact i have huge collection of these files and i need to generate spatial data in esri supported vector format. Actually i am in dilemma how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know where the files in those formats come from, then I think you should take advice from @ChadCooper's comment (which matches my research) and contact Magellan to confirm whether these formats belong to one of their applications.